# Unable to upload file using Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I am currently working on a project in Android Studio together with a classmate. We are struggling to effectively upload files (more specifically images). We use the webview property for this project. We used countless resources, both from stackoverflow and outside sources but haven't found a solution as of yet.

We are running this app on a OnePlus 6T using Android Pie(9.0).

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        ((WebSettings) webSettings).setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("our website here");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.fps.cardtool">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you need to add permission for accessing storage, without it you might not be able to read file.

Comment: We just added the READ and WRITE permissions (external storage I assume). However when we tested the app once more it still did not let us upload anything.

Comment: have you enabled permission dynamically, above android m you need to provide them dynamically. you can try by enabling those permission from application settings.

Comment: Currently looking into that, searching for "permissions" in the settings tab in Studio but none seem to point in the direction of any storage. Unless I am looking in the wrong place?

Comment: from application-> select your application -> there will permission option for it.

Comment: We just set the storage permission to true on the device we ran it on, however with the permission granted on the device AND inserted into the studio code (read and write) it still does nothing. The button doesn't do anything, it shows a tap effect but that's literally it.

Comment: Hi, I tried this [link](https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-upload-file-in-webview-in-android) and it works in my website, file uploaded to my server. 
That example show upload in imgur website.

Answer (score 0):

Set enabled to load images.

**Use this code**

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("our website here");
```

Comment: Not sure if this changes the definition of the question entirely but: the file chooser in it's entirety is not working, nothing shows up it's basically a plain button with no function at this point.

Comment: I didn't get your point actually what you want exactly? Webview use for external URL in your application.

Comment: The problem is that when we press the choose file button nothing happens. The URL is the site on which the project is stationed, however on android the file chooser does not pop up when we press the button. At this point we tried:

- Granting the app permission to use the storage of the device
- Giving the application read and write permissions

And last we tried the possible solution above which also did not work.

Comment: Please visit this [URL](http://whats-online.info/science-and-tutorials/18/Android-java-tutorial--Webview-file-upload-on-Facebook/) it might be helpful to you.

Comment: Tried following those instructions however we had a lot of import errors, some of which we couldn't solve by importing classes/modules. It's becoming really frustrating because we've been dealing with this for a week now.

Comment: because you're working on latest Android versions and the reference URL is workable for old but its only answer available. So fix it import issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Closing thread due to inability to figure out an effective solution.**

I know I can't technically close a thread but I figured a notice might be nice.